# In what situations would one choose v-text over the "mustache" syntax?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

According to the [VueJS docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-text), `<span v-text="msg"></span>` is the same as `<span>{{msg}}</span>`. Out of really nothing other than habit I always use the "mustache" syntax to bind data. In what situations would one choose to use `v-text` instead, and why?

Comment: I can't think of a time I've *ever* used it.

Answer (score 8):

One reason you might want to use v-text is if you need to pre-render some markup on the server, but also have it bind client-side. For example:

`<span v-text="msg">This message was pre-rendered from the server.</span>`

That way the `{{msg}}` syntax doesn't get in the way of the content.

Comment: Then why is https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-child-content.html included in Vue's "essential" ruleset?

Answer (score 3):

This directive updates a html-node with innerContent. Html will not be rendered like with v-html. You can use v-text to have your template look other but  internally, {{ Mustache }} interpolations are also compiled as a v-text direcitve.

Comment: “(…) internally, {{ Mustache }} interpolations are also compiled as a v-text direcitve.”


Hey @Reiner, do you have a reference for this? Some GitHub link, perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: Yes @gnclmorais your can read about that literally in the documentation https://012.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-text and even in the current documentation https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-text

Comment: Thanks, @Reiner. I looked into the most recent documentation and didn’t see it there, as your latter link shows; but the former link indeed explains that. Great!

Comment: Security note, per Vue docs: `Using v-html with user-supplied data can be dangerous. It is suggested that you only use v-html when you are absolutely sure about the security of the data source, or pipe it through a custom filter that sanitizes untrusted HTML.`

Answer (score 1):

**v-text**, or "Directive Syntax" interpolates a property value as an HTML element's text.

If you need to bind to a part of the element only you need to use Semantic syntax (`{{mustache}}`).

For example, if you had `<h4>Hi, this is the text : {{text}}</h4>` then, during the update only what's inside `{{text}}` would be replaced. However, if you use `v-text` it will replace the whole content of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, for situations where you mistakenly use **v-text** when your variable contains mark up, it will be rendered as raw html in the browser, just a gotcha to watch out for.